# Which object shows "Chatter Following" data?

Tags: chatter, subscriber

I'm trying to import chatter data into an org. As part of that, I'm trying to import data on which users are following which users.

Which object shows that relationship? I'm looking for API names if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for **[`EntitySubscription`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm)**:

> ## EntitySubscription
>
> Represents a subscription for a user following a record or another user. This object is available in API version 34.0 and later.
>
> A user can subscribe to a record or to another user. Changes to the record and updates from the users are displayed in the Chatter feed on the user's home page, which is a useful way to stay up-to-date with other users and with changes made to records in Salesforce. Feeds are available in API version 18.0 and later.